# Can't find site in admin center

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm working on tenant to tenant migration, they gave me a global admin on source tenant.

I can't find https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Intranet/SitePages/home.aspx listed in active/deleted sites, nor does it show up with a get-sposite. Get-sposite -identity  doens't work either

All the other sites are Team sites so I'm thinking I don't need to worry about them as I'll be using BitTitan Migrationwiz Collab.

Also what's a decent migration software for SPO tenant to tenant, BitTitan seems underdeveloped compared to the rest of their offerings. I've used them so far for Exchange on premise to O365 and Lotus Notes to O365 migration.

Comment: Could you access the site successfully? 

From your description, it seems the site has been deleted permanently or the site never exists.

Comment: @Julie_MSFT yes I can access the site directly via url.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the URL I'm thinking that /intranet is a sub-web of the root Site collection.  It does not appear that /intranet is a site collection, thus it is not listed as a site collection in the admin center.

For tenant to tenant migrations looks at ShareGate. Mover.io is a free option worth looking at, but I don't think it is all the way there yet.

Comment: thanks for your time. They decided not to move whatever that site was, we'll just be migrating mailboxes, onedrive, and Teams with BitTitan.